# no results when file is uppercase, python

Tags: python, text-files, match, uppercase

```
#!/usr/bin/python

catalog=open("physicsjournals2.txt","r")
catalogdata=catalog.readlines()

import glob
import os
import sys

directories = ['Analytica Chimica Acta' , 'Analytical and Bioanalytical Chemistry' , 'Journal of Chromatography A' , 'Sensors' , 'Talanta' , 'Carbohydrate Polymers' , 'Dyes and Pigments' , 'Food Chemistry' , 'Food Hydrocolloids' , 'Journal of Agricultural and Food Chemistry' , 'Microporous and Mesoporous Materials' , 'Dalton Transactions' , 'European Journal of Inorganic Chemistry' , 'Organometallics' , 'Angewandte Chemie - International Edition' , 'Journal of the American Chemical Society' , 'Tetrahedron - Asymmetry' , 'Biomacromolecules' , 'Journal of Organic Chemistry' , 'Organic Letters' , 'Advanced Materials' , 'Colloids and Surfaces B - Biointerfaces' , 'Journal of Physical Chemistry B' , 'Journal of Physical Chemistry C' , 'Langmuir' , 'Physical Chemistry Chemical Physics' , 'Journal of Membrane Science' , 'Macromolecular Bioscience' , 'Macromolecules' , 'Plasma Processes and Polymers']

catalogRecs = {}

for line in catalogdata:
    rec = "SO " + line.strip()
    catalogRecs[rec] = True

for folder in directories:
    savedrecfilenames = glob.glob(os.path.join(folder, "savedrecs (*).txt journals.txt"))
    #print savedrecfilenames
    for savedrecfilename in savedrecfilenames:
        i = 0
        savedrecfile=open(savedrecfilename,"r")
        fdata=savedrecfile.readlines()
        for line in fdata:
            name = line.strip()
            #print name
            if catalogRecs.has_key(name):
                i+=1
        #print savedrecfilename + " cited " + str(i) + " sources."
        ## veya sadece sayi outputlamak istersen
        print str(i)
```

when I use this code to get results, when the physicsjournals2 (txt) catalog has lines that are both uppercase and lowercase, I get results. However, I realized that these results are smaller numbers that they need to be, so I changed the catalog's lines to uppercase (letters in my savedrecs txt files are all uppercase, so it would be better matched), however I got zero results. Besides physicsjournals2, all my other uppercase catalogs yields results.
How must I modify the catalog physicsjournals2 ?

Comment: What is content of `physicsjournals2.txt`?

Comment: Names of journals. Some of them are completely uppercase, some of them lowercase with capital first letters. One journal name per line.

Comment: so what are you getting as output?

Comment: You should show us the file `physicsjournals2.txt`  and your output of your script...

Answer (score 0):

You can change this part of your code:

```
for line in catalogdata:
    rec = "SO " + line.strip().lower()
    catalogRecs[rec] = True
```